# Ajax form submission not work in conjunction with JQuery mouse events (mouseenter and mouseleave)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony-3.4

I can't figure out why the form redirects after being submitted. So, this is how my code works: When the mouse is entered (mouseenter) the button edit appears. When this button is clicked I send ajax request to the server, and I get as response a form with select options, so far so good. But, when I choose (select) something and hit update, the form redirects despite the fact that I wrote evt.preventDefault(), and subsequently ajax failed working. I got stuck and I can't figure out where the bug is. I appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```js
$('div.js-service-company').mouseenter(function(evt) {
  const thisDiv = $(this);
  const link = $(this).children().children('a');
  const p = $(this).children();
  let url = link.attr('href');
  let currentTicketState = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
  const ticketId = link.attr('data-id');

  if (allowedTicketStates.includes(currentTicketState)) {

    const btn = $('<button/>', {
      type: 'submit',
      name: 'serviceCompanyData',
      class: 'btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit-service-company',
      text: 'Edit'
    });

    p.append(btn);

    $('button.btn-edit-service-company').click(function(btn) {
      btn.preventDefault();
      const thisBtn = $(this);

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '{{ path('
        admin_cms3_core_ticket_getServiceCompany ') }}',
        data: {
          ticketId: ticketId,
        },
        success: response => {
          link.parent('p').append(response);
          link.hide();
          thisBtn.hide();
          $('div.js-service-company').off("mouseenter");
        },
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus) => {
          console.log("Error occurred: " + textStatus)
        }
      });

    });
    // this is where the form submission occurres
    $('form#service-company-form').submit(function(evt2) {
      evt2.preventDefault();

      const form = $(this);
      const type = form.attr('method');
      const thisUrl = form.attr('action');

      $.ajax({
        type,
        url: thisUrl,
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: response => {
          $('body div').removeClass("loader_wrap loader_background");
          form.hide();
          link.text(response.serviceCompany);
          link.show();
        },
        error: err => {
          console.log(err)
        }
      });
    });
  }
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $('button.btn-edit-service-company').hide();
  const objectId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('.service_company-'.concat(`${objectId}`)).hide();
});
```

```
The html code:
```

```html
<td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-string" objectid="326966">

  <div class="js-service-company">
    <p>
      <a data-id="326966" href="/app_dev.php/cms3/core/company/6/show?state=closed1">Text_01</a>
    </p>
    Company Name
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I removed the first line of the snippet since it does not run

Comment: I do not understand why you do not just show/hide the button on hover instead of this overly complex set of event handlers you add and remove

Comment: There is so much wrong with the above code. Please post the HTML and perhaps we can fix it. For one, add the button in the HTML and hide it with CSS. Then you can toggle it with script instead of adding it on each mouseover

Comment: @mplungjan I have included the html code, please check.

Comment: And how to test this? `if (allowedTicketStates.includes(currentTicketState)) {`

Comment: @mplungjan, here I'm just checking if the string is in the url like so: const allowedTicketStates = ["new", "planned", "completed", "pending", "approved"];

Comment: Your example is "closed1"

Comment: @mplungjan, I left it out by mistake. It's just a string like so "closed1".

Comment: Here is what I meant https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c9m26zhr/ - it is not complete but gives you an idea

Answer (score 0):

The event you got is selecting an element which is not present in DOM. After your ajax call you inject new markup to the dom. To bind your events to these elements you can use the `.on` method:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#service-company-form', function (evt2) {
    evt2.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

As mplungjan suggested is this syntax better

```
$('#service-company-form').on('submit', function (evt2) {
    evt2.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

because jQuery will not listen on every submits in `document` and filter for the selector. This will only fire when `#service-company-form` is submitted.

Comment: Why not `$("#service-company-form").on('submit', function (evt2) {
    evt2.preventDefault();
    // ...
});`

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for your answer. I've tried this way, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @Capfer can you place an `alert()` before `evt2.preventDefault();` to be sure you get into that listener.

Comment: @kmgt, I've already tried this way before posting my question. It did not work for me

Comment: @Capfer and a strip of that HTML.

Comment: the submit event handler needs to go OUTSIDE the other code